# Solve for the missing variable with known formula

Tags: c++, formula, solver

This is what I'm doing at the moment, but I'm just wondering if there is perhaps a better way?

My Kinematic Variable class just holds a long double value and a bool if the variable has been set or not.  I overloaded the = assignment operator.

```
// v_f = v_o + a*t
bool KinematicEquations::equation_vat(KinematicVariable &vo, KinematicVariable &vf,
                                      KinematicVariable &a, KinematicVariable &t)
{
    if (vf.isUsed() && vo.isUsed() && a.isUsed())
        t = (vf.value() - vo.value()) / a.value();  // t = (vf - vo)/a
    else if (vf.isUsed() && vo.isUsed() && t.isUsed())
        a = (vf.value() - vo.value()) / a.value();  // a = (vf - vo)/t
    else if (vf.isUsed() && t.isUsed() && a.isUsed())
        vo = vf.value() - a.value() * t.value(); // vo = vf - a*t
    else if (vo.isUsed() && t.isUsed() && a.isUsed())
        vf = vo.value() + a.value() * t.value(); // vf = vo + at
    else
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem particularly elegant but that seems like more a design issue with the interface of`KinematicEquations` than anything else, and it's hard to tell how you might improve it without more context.

Comment: Maybe you would be better off rewriting the expression in terms of functions like `v_f=Add[v_o,Multiply[a,t]]` and then inverting this recursively to solve for the desired variable. This will reduce the amount of hardcoded solvers needed.

Comment: Kinematic equations is a set of about 3 "main" equations that calculate the movement of an object on a plane in 1 dimension.  Each equation has 3 variables and can solve for the 4th.  This is 1 of the simpler formulas of the set.

Comment: @WHOEVENCARES I suppose you could also use a CAS (computer algebra system) or even submit it to the W|A API in the worst case scenario. What is the problem you were trying to solve before you created this one? :)

Comment: @WHOEVENCARES I'm not a fan of the idea of using `isUsed() == true` to mean "given variable" and `isUsed() == false` to mean "variable to solve for", it seems error prone. Basically it means you'll have to check `isUsed()` all the time to do anything, and you might forget...cannot say how to redesign it without more context though

Comment: That's the only way I can think of to represent if the variable is already set, since negative values and 0 values are acceptable inputs.

Comment: @WHOEVENCARES Perhaps you can make two subclasses of `KinematicVariable`: One stores a numerical value and the other represents the symbolic variable. Your code will be a bit messier due to casting but then it should be impossible to mix up the given variables with the variables you are solving for.

Answer (score 2):

What I would consider is that with `t = 0` and/or `a = 0` this equation is more-or-less useless. It results in `vo = vf`. So, I would say check them first. A user with physics knowledge could wrap their head around the idea that if t or a is zero you must be solving for them:

```
bool KinematicEquations::equation_vat(KinematicVariable &vo, KinematicVariable &vf,
                                      KinematicVariable &a, KinematicVariable &t)
{
    if (t == 0)
        t = (vf.value() - vo.value()) / a.value();  // t = (vf - vo)/a
    else if (a == 0)
        a = (vf.value() - vo.value()) / a.value();  // a = (vf - vo)/t
    else if (vf.isUsed())
        vo = vf.value() - a.value() * t.value(); // vo = vf - a*t
    else if (vo.isUsed())
        vf = vo.value() + a.value() * t.value(); // vf = vo + at
    else
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

Doing this should save you a couple ops at least. Initialize the variables to `0` if they haven't been used they will have `0`s and all is well. Further, by the time you get to the last two you already know for certain that `a` and `t` are used so no need to check. I think this is a fair solution based on the perceived knowledge of the user.